# Console view is empty in Eclipse with Maven 3.5.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-3, m2eclipse, m2e

The Console view does not show any output when the Maven is configured to external Maven installation in Eclipse.

Please refer to the screenshots for more details.

[image: Console Out put screenshot]

[image: Maven Configuration screenshot]

The Console is displayed when *Maven*  → *Installations* is configured for EMBEDDED Maven.

My external Maven version: 3.5.0, Eclipse Luna.

TIA

Comment: are you sure that this is the console window for maven?

Comment: Hi @ScaryWombat ,Yes It is the maven console, it works fine when it is configured for the embedded Maven.

Comment: @ScaryWombat AFAIK, there's just one console view in Eclipse and that's for the output of all plugins (at least it was like that in the not too distant past). IIRC there's also at least one question regarding this here on SO. The only other consoles I'm aware of are from plugins that supply console access like PuTTY, KiTTY, and the like.

Comment: What do you expect to be displayed in the console? Which `mvn` command(s) have you defined in your run configuration(s)?

Comment: @GeroldBroser I was using mvn clean install , just the build command and wanted to see the build out put

Comment: Maven 3.5.0 is just 3 weeks old. I don't know whether the m2e Eclipse plugin has been updated to support it already. Can you try it with the previous v3.3.9 just to be sure it isn't that?

Comment: @GeroldBroser Yes you are correct, it is the issue with the new version , it worked for V3.3.9 . Thanks a lot

Comment: Pleased that I was of help. I created an answer from my comment since comments aren't the prominent and not read first by searchers in general. You can accept it and also upvote it for extra appreciation, see also [_Help Center_ > _Reputation & Moderation_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reputation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you're using [Maven's brand new v3.5.0 that's just three weeks old](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.maven%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven%22). I don't know whether the [m2e Eclipse plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) has been updated to support it already. I performed *Help* → *Check for Updates* in Eclipse and there wasn't any.

I'd try Maven's previous v3.3.9 which I experienced to be stable for 1.5 years now to see whether it works with that.